# How to return id in JSON (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Ruby on Rails.

My `http://localhost:3000/locations.json` returns the following:

```
[{
  "name":"ABC",
  "address":"xyz",
  "latitude":12.3,
  "longitude":14.5,
  "url":"http://localhost:3000/locations/1.json"
}]
```

How to modify the `locations_controller.rb` in order for the JSON to return the `id`, without parsing the URL?

```
[{
  "id":1,
  "name":"ABC",
  "address":"xyz",
  "latitude":12.3,
  "longitude":14.5,
  "url":"http://localhost:3000/locations/1.json"
}]
```

My current `locations_controller.rb` contains this:

```
def index
  puts "index"
  @locations = Location.all
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: How do you build the json? Do you use json serializer? Did you overrule `as_json` in the model? Which rails version are you using?

Comment: I use scaffolding which auto generates the locations_controller.rb and can return the result in json format automatically. I use ruby 2.0, rails 4.0. Thanks.

Comment: look at the Location source, is there a to_json method? i think that the ID should be included in the json by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue.

Need to change to the following:

```
def index
 puts "index"
 @locations = Location.all
end
```

to

```
 def index
     @locations = Location.all
     respond_to do |format|  
        format.html #index.html.erb
        format.xml  { render :xml => @locations }
        format.json  { render :json => @locations }
     end
 end`
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a framework like [Rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) that gives you greater control over the output of the json. This would allow you to easily specify what you would like included in the json response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder)

```
# @people = People.all

json.array! @people, :id, :name

# => [ { "id": 1, "name": "David" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Jamie" } ]
```